# d3.format wont keep trailing zero

Tags: javascript, ember.js, d3.js

I'm using d3.round(num,2) to round a number from say, 2.567 to 2.57.  My problem is that when I do this, I want 2 decimal numbers of precision to be used at all times/regardless of if it is a zero.

when I have a number like 2.201, I want the display to be 2.20, and instead am coming up with 2.2.  Is there any way to format the round function to always include zeroes?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: used num.toFixed(2) and that works, but I am returning d3.format("$")(num.toFixed(2)) and that is only returning $2.3, which is the reason I needed this, I am looking to display a price. If anyone has help to offer with that, it would be great, thank you

Comment: Because numbers don't have trailing zeros. Native [`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) does the trick, but it returns a string.

Comment: @Teemu - see new edit, any other help you can offer? that did work so thank you for that but d3.format overrode it

Comment: Drop the d3, or do it this way: `(d3.format("$")(num)).toFixed(2)`.

Comment: To format to currency with 2 decimales; `format("$,.2f");`

Comment: @cyrbil thank you, yours worked, so did Nitish's. thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you hit the up arrow if i helped as it encourage and reward people to contribute to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Totally forgot - did it on the Answer, my bad all fixed! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
d3.format("$.3n")(num);
```